# Reading is much faster than writing with AEGIS-128

Tags: encryption, authentication, performance, dm-crypt

I want to use cryptographic integrity checking in Linux. Naturally, I measured performance of different implementations on my computer in order to choose the best. The block device is in `tmpfs`, in other words, RAM. Hence the performance is not constrained by SSD.

Long story short, writing with AEGIS-128 is considerably slower than writing with AES-XTS and SHA-1 while their relationship for reading is reverse. Reading with AEGIS-128 is 7 times faster than writing. This seems wrong. If it is correct, considering that NVMe SSDs in the price range from 100 to 150 USD offer a throughput at about 3 GiB/s, the throughput of a cipher at 1 GiB/s is disappointing.

Maybe, I set up `dm-crypt/dm-integrity` wrong? Is this a known issue with AEGIS-128? Can anybody replicate my results? I wrote a [whole blog post about this](https://beroal.livejournal.com/80155.html), but here I post only relevant information.

Performance results in the CSV format:

```
encryption/integrity/journal,"Sequential reading, MiB/s","Sequential writing, MiB/s"
aegis128-random/aead/yes,6213.68,906.91
aes-xts-plain64/hmac-sha1/yes,2030.40,1722.06
```

Benchmark commands:

mode: aegis128-random/aead/yes

```
cryptsetup --type luks2 --cipher aegis128-random --key-size 128 --integrity aead --sector-size 4096 --key-file /tmp/key --iter-time 100 luksFormat /tmp/benchmark
cryptsetup --key-file /tmp/key open /tmp/benchmark benchmark
$BENCHMARK_COMMANDS
cryptsetup close benchmark
```

mode: aes-xts-plain64/hmac-sha1/yes

```
cryptsetup --type luks2 --sector-size 4096 --key-file /tmp/key --cipher aes-xts-plain64 --integrity hmac-sha1 --iter-time 100 luksFormat /tmp/benchmark
cryptsetup --key-file /tmp/key open /tmp/benchmark benchmark
$BENCHMARK_COMMANDS
cryptsetup close benchmark
```

where `BENCHMARK_COMMANDS` are

```
fio --rw write --filename $BLOCK_DEVICE a.fio
fio --rw read --filename $BLOCK_DEVICE a.fio
```

where `a.fio` contains

```
[global]
bs=1M
iodepth=64
ioengine=libaio
gtod_reduce=1
numjobs=4
group_reporting=1
time_based
runtime=10

[job]
```

`BLOCK_DEVICE` is `/dev/mapper/benchmark`.